# Applying a filter, using pivot and adding rows on a file with sheets locked by a macro

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot

I lock and unlock a file in one time using the below macros (1 and 2):

I would like to amend these macros to

- filter tables
- use pivot tables
- add lines to table

I want to combine macros 1 and 2 to integrate the specifics of macro 3.

Macros 1 and 2 were found online and macro 3 was recorded.

**macros 1 and 2**

```vb
Sub ProtectAllWorksheets()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Pwd As String
    Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Protect Worksheets")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=Pwd
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub UnProtectAllWorksheets()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Pwd As String
    Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to unprotect all worksheets", "Unprotect Worksheets")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=Pwd
    Next ws
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have entered an incorect password. All worksheets could not " & _
          "be unprotected.", vbCritical, "Incorect Password"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

**Macro 3**

```vb
Sub lock1sheetWFilter()
    ' lock1sheetWFilter Macro
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
      , AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:= _
      True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my own answer:
we just have to modify the code of macro 1 to the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProtectAllWorksheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Pwd As String
    Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Protect Worksheets")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
           , AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:= _
            True
    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```